# how can I secure my static ip router?

Tags: exploit, ipsec, ip

hi I have a static ip and someone is hacking my computer trought it I tried to format my computer and making a clean install but he keeps penetrating it this time i tried to install the AV before pluging my computer to the internet but since it requires updates I asume he can use some exploits to bypass its firewall I try reseting my router and I always have the same IP what should i do? 
its a remote exploit I assume since I cant update my computer before his attack

Comment: a firewall can not protect the computer from its user: any software that you install and run on the computer might have an undiscovered/unpatched vulnerability that waiting to be xploited.

Answer (score 1):

Unplug your router from the internet, power down your normal machine and then connect another fully patched machine to your router.

Log into the admin panel, change the administrator password to a new, strong password and delete any other users from the router. Make a note of any internet connection settings. It might be worth doing a factory reset to make sure that there are no port forwarding rules or anything else setup. If you do this, check that the password is still your new one afterwards. Check that all the remote access settings are turned off (web, telnet, etc) and export the configuration to your clean machine if your router supports this.

Connect the router to the internet and then run [Shields Up](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2) to verify that all service ports are Closed or Stealth. If any come up as Open, go into your router config and close them. Once Shields Up has given you the thumbs up, disconnect your router again from the internet and reformat your attacked machine. Use the clean machine to manually download updates which can be installed to the original machine (OS as well as AV). Don't connect your original machine to the router or to the internet until it is fully up to date (you'll of course have to check which updates you need manually).

Yes this approach requires a separate machine, but you have no choice unless you can get your original machine patched and up to date without connecting through your targeted router.